# Changing image background color

Tags: macos, image-editing, pixelmator

I have a personal image with a grey background, I want to change the background color to white.

I have Pixelmator, but other solutions are welcome as well.

Comment: @slhck Photography faq states - `it is not about... Image Manipulation (outside of the Photography context)` - I'm not sure if they'd accept this. I'll try askin' them

Comment: Post the image in best resolution and maybe someone will do it for you.

Comment: What about MS-Paint? :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you can use the Magic Wand tool:

[image: pointing out exactly where is the magic wand tool]

If you dont see the tools pane for the Magic Wand Tool, use the <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>

After selecting the tool, click and hold on where the grey background is, and move the cursor to increase/decrease the tolerance. Make sure the tolerance is just right, and covers the whole of the background, but not reaching the picture:

[image: showing tolerance]

Once the area you want is selected, select the Paint Bucket tool. You then select the colour that you want from the swatches, which is white (if you dont see it press <kbd>⌘ Command</kbd>+<kbd>6</kbd>). Now click the image with the paint bucket and viola, a white background!

[image: done]

Save, Quit. Done.